# iOS - How to perform sqlite3 write operation correctly in multithreading?

Tags: ios, multithreading, sqlite

If I perform sqlite3 write(insert/update/delete) operation, my app crashed with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` sometimes.

Create `dispatch_queue_t`:

```
dispatch_queue_create("example.testQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
```

`-dealData: paramsarray:`

```
- (BOOL)dealData:(NSString *)sql paramsarray:(NSArray *)params {
    __block BOOL result = NO;
    dispatch_sync(_dbQueue, ^{
        sqlite3_stmt *stmt = nil;

        //prepare
        int code = sqlite3_prepare_v2(self.sqlite, [sql UTF8String], -1, &stmt, NULL);
        if (code != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"SQL error:%@, %@, %s", sql, params, sqlite3_errmsg((__bridge sqlite3 *)(self)));
        }
        else {
            //bind
            for (int i=0; i<params.count; i++) {
                NSString *value = safeString([params objectAtIndex:i]);
                sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, i+1, [value UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            }

            //step
            if(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ERROR) { // crash at this line
                NSLog(@"SQL step failed:%@", sql);
            }
            else {
                sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
                result = YES;
            }
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

It seems cause by writing data at same time in multiple thread. I don't know how to handle this problem.

Comment: show your full code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea to use a dispatch queue for this is correct, you just cannot use a concurrent queue as this still runs blocks in parallel. Just switch over to a serial queue by using `DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL`.

Another option would be to not care about the synchronisation yourself and instead pass the `SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX` flag when opening your database connection to run it in serialised mode.

Comment: I replace `sqlite3_open` with `sqlite3_open_v2` and pass the `SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX` flag now, and it works fine. Do I need remove `dispatch_sync` operation code?

Comment: It won't hurt, so you can leave it in, even though it is not necessary any more.